# How to use list of User_Id's from Twitter API?

Tags: arrays, api, twitter, output

I'm trying to make the list into an array I can use to then do other stuff with the data. But it itself seems to be some other form of collected data, with an intro text "{ ids: " and commas separating everything. So when I try to make an array of it, it all just gets put into the first index, making it unusable.

How do I make this list into an array?

Comment: "{ids:" looks like a string. If that's the case you would need to convert the string to a JSON object. To do that conversion you probably would want to use a suitable library or built-in function in the computer language that you are working with.

Comment: What language and/or library are you using client-side to parse the json you get from twitter?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Thanks everyone for contributing. It's Javascript. and for JSON, it's split into parts, like: data.ids[0]

(and ids is an array)